# Error "cannot implicitly convert type string to decimal"

Tags: c#

am trying to get my values displayed in the form of currency.i have a code that am making use of which should convert string to decimal.am getting the error that it can not convert the string to decimal.the error is at the line of code where i have string.format.

```
string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];

for (int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    y[i] = string.Format("{0:##,##0.00}",Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]));
}
```

Comment: `string.Format` returns string, but you're assigning to `decimal` array. You need to use `Convert.ToDecimal` or `decimal.Parse` from string value or directly insert `dt.Rows[i][j]` as decimal.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, thanks, i have changed it to  y[i] = Convert.ToDecimal("{0:##,##0.00}",Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1])); but am now getting this error from where i have convert.toint32 that "cannot convert from int to system.IFormat provider

Comment: Why not just `string.Format("{0:##,##0.00}", dt.Rows[i][1].ToString())`? If that column contains decimal value, it will losing precision when converting to `int`. If you want straight decimal conversion, just do `Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i][1])`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
```

to:

```
string[] y = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
```

and use the following conversion:

```
y[i] = string.Format("{0:##,##0.00}", dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
```

Alternatively, if you dont't want to change the type of `y`:

```
y[i] = Decimal.Parse(dt.Rows[i][1]);
```

With this last approach, if you need more control in order to deal with the current numbers format, use this version of `Decimal.Parse`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i have changed it as you suggested but now am getting error at this line of code  BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = y}); the error is Data=y which says"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'decimal[]'" that is where i have Data=y

Answer (score 0):

You try to put a string in a decimal which is wrong.
You should use the default currency formater and change your decimal in string :

```
string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

string[] y = new string[dt.Rows.Count];

for (int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
   y[i] = int.Parse(dt.Rows[i][1]).ToString("C2");
}
```

Comment: i have changed it accordinfly to this 
        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        string[] y = new string[dt.Rows.Count];//decimal[] y = new decimal[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            y[i] = string.Format("{0:##,##0.00}", Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]));//Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
        BarChart1.Series.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.BarChartSeries { Data = y}); but am getting the error here at Data=y which says"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'decimal[]'"

Comment: What line needs a string[] ? If it is BarChart, then you cannot format the values, just use decimal without currency format.

Comment: i want those values to be like this; instead of having 6200 i want them to be 6,200.00